# Robots.txt file not updating

Tags: security, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, robots.txt

One of our website **robots.txt** file is not getting updated,deleted **.htaccess** and **robots.txt** file from root folder from one of the suggested answers
[Why does Google Webmaster Tools say my whole site is blocked by robots.txt when I have no robots.txt?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142293/why-does-google-webmaster-tools-say-my-whole-site-is-blocked-by-robots-txt-when)

I thought may be some plugin conflict.So I have completely deactivated Yoast SEO and Security plugin which is affecting the file. but still **robots.txt** file displays me as

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
```

Any other suggestion or help,which can help me in updating the file will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you are actually seeing a real robots.txt file that says that, feel free to delete it (i.e. through FTP).

Comment: I have already deleted the robots.txt file from root folder via ftp,but still i can see the same output

Comment: You can still see the same output _where_ ?

Comment: I can still see the same output in my website example URL::mywebsite.com/robots.txt

Comment: If the file is not there, but you can still access it via the URL, it is most likely being generated by WordPress. You're sure the "Discourage search engines..." setting in WordPress is unchecked?

Comment: Yes Settings->reading ->Search Engine Visibility   checkbox is  unchecked already

Comment: any answers please

Comment: Have you tried to turn off all plugins? Can be robots.txt cached by your browser or server?

Comment: I have deactivated my entire plugin ,and deleted the robots.txt file as well,but still the same thing is displayed

Comment: Check with your host. This doesn't sound like a WordPress problem.